# Is my Matlab code correctly implementing this given algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, backwards-compatibility

I am getting some wrong results and I couldn't locate any mistake in my code, so I was thinking if any of you can figure out if I am implementing this [Binomial-Lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_options_pricing_model) algorithm correctly or not. Here's what I am getting as results and what I expect from as my results:

**Actual Results:** 
I start with `[S0,K,sigma,r,T,nColumn]=[1.5295e+009,6e+008,0.0023,0.12,20,15]` and I get `p=32.5955` , `price=-6.0e+18` and `BLOV_lattice` as shown in figure 1.

**Expected Results:**

1. `p` is probability, so it should not be greater than 1. Even if I increase the `nColumn` to 1000, still the `p` is greater than 1 in the above actual results.
2. `price` should come out to be same as `S0` , the number I start with in the first column, after backward induction i.e. there should be backwards-compatibility.

**Figure 1: BLOV_lattice**
[image]

**My Matlab Code is:**

```
function [price,BLOV_lattice]=BLOV_general(S0,K,sigma,r,T,nColumn)

% BLOV stands for Binomial Lattice Option Valuation

%% Constant parameters
del_T=T./nColumn; % where n is the number of columns in binomial lattice
u=exp(sigma.*sqrt(del_T));
d=1./u;
p=(exp(r.*del_T)-d)./(u-d);
a=exp(-r.*del_T);

%% Initializing the lattice
Stree=zeros(nColumn+1,nColumn+1);
BLOV_lattice=zeros(nColumn+1,nColumn+1);

%% Developing the lattice

%# Forward induction

for i=0:nColumn
    for j=0:i
        Stree(j+1,i+1)=S0.*(u.^j)*(d.^(i-j));
    end
end
for i=0:nColumn
    BLOV_lattice(i+1,nColumn+1)=max(Stree(i+1,nColumn+1)-K,0);
end

%# Backward induction

for i=nColumn:-1:1
    for j=0:i-1
        BLOV_lattice(j+1,i)=a.*(((1-p).*BLOV_lattice(j+1,i+1))+(p.*BLOV_lattice(j+2,i+1)));
    end
end
price=BLOV_lattice(1,1);

%% Converting the lattice of upper traingular matrix to a tree format

N = size(BLOV_lattice,1);  %# The size of the rows and columns in BLOV_lattice
BLOV_lattice = full(spdiags(spdiags(BLOV_lattice),(1-N):2:(N-1),zeros(2*N-1,N)));
```

**References:**

- Cox, John C., Stephen A. Ross, and Mark Rubinstein. 1979. "Option Pricing: A Simplified Approach." Journal of Financial Economics 7: 229-263.
- E. Georgiadis, "Binomial Options Pricing Has No Closed-Form Solution". Algorithmic Finance Forthcoming (2011).
- Richard J. Rendleman, Jr. and Brit J. Bartter. 1979. "Two-State Option Pricing". Journal of Finance 24: 1093-1110. doi:10.2307/2327237

Comment: Does the size of the question seems overwhelming or what? Just wondering because of no answer...

Comment: @H_S: Perhaps you have some reference where you got your formulas? Care to double check with it? You may share it with us as well. Thanks

Comment: @eat: You can look at this wikipedia article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_options_pricing_model) or page 8 on http://www.slb.com/~/media/Files/resources/oilfield_review/ors03/win03/p4_19.ashx or http://faculty.darden.virginia.edu/conroyb/derivatives/Binomial%20Option%20Pricing%20_f-0943_.pdf

Comment: @H_S: After quick skimming non of those on-line references don't indicate that `p=(exp(r.*del_T)-d)./(u-d)`. Where did you get this?

Comment: @eat: I gave you so many references and you couldn't find `p=(exp(r.*del_T)-d)./(u-d)` in any? It's in wikipedia link as well as slb.com link (on page 9) to name a few.

Comment: Your Wikipedia link lists the probability formula as `p = (exp((r-q)*deltaT)-d)/(u-d)`. Is it valid for you to assume `q = 0`? Could that be the source of your error?

Comment: gnovice: Yes, `q` can be `0`. That is not an issue!

Comment: @H_S: Have you tried to calculate with my suggestion `p= (1- d)/ (u- d)`?

Comment: @eat: Sorry eat, but I can't use that formula. The one I showed you is there in the literature and is correct!

Comment: @H_S: But your references mention also `q` which you haven't defined. As I insisted already that your references discuss on `p = (exp((r-q)*deltaT)-d)/(u-d)` but not on `p=(exp(r.*del_T)-d)./(u-d)`. Also there exists case that `q==r` and then `p` boils down to be `p= (1- d)/ (u- d)`. So why have you ignored `q`? Answering that question my give hint how to properly calculate `p`!. Thanks

Comment: Actually `q` can be zero. It's not for my case specifically, but also in the literature they define it that way. When no dividend is paid for each year then `q=0`.

Comment: @eat: Thanks for trying to help BTW!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, your formulation of `p` as `p=(exp(r.*del_T)-d)./(u-d)` is not defined (clearly as such) anywhere in your references.

From your code it's not so straightforward to deduce what kind of options you are trying to valuate.

Closest I can get is to interpret that `p` (in your case) simply boils down to be `p= (1- d)/ (u- d)`, which with your parameters will be `0.49934`. (At least a reasonable value to be interpreted as probability!)